# how to convert qt4 python2.7 application to windows exe file?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created a very basic application using qt4 with two buttons and functionality.I tried to convert this to exe for windows system using pyinstaller, py2exe and cz_freeze but it is not working please help

Comment: Instead of asking a general question that many times have been made, so your current question could be marked as duplicate or fall into the off-topic: why my code is not working ?. I would recommend you reformulate your question pointing out the errors you get in your attempts.

Comment: I am able to make a build exe from the code but it is not working while if I make it executable for ubuntu it is working fine.